# Problem adding fields with multiple images in Laravel

Tags: laravel

How to solve this problem of adding data with uploading multiple images
This is the frontend code

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ URL::route('employees.store') }}"  enctype="multipart/form-data" id="FormEmployees" class="Employees">
    @csrf

    <section class="content">
    <!-- Main content -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                <label for="First_Name">First Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="First_Name" class="form-control"
                id="First_Name" placeholder="Enter First Name" >
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                <label for="Last_Name">Last Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="Last_Name" class="form-control"
                id="Last_Name" placeholder="Enter Last Name" >
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                <label for="Birth_Date">Birth Date</label>
                <input type="date" name="Birth_Date" class="form-control"
                id="Birth_Date">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                <label for="Official_Email">Official Email</label>
                <input type="email" name="Official_Email" class="form-control"
                id="Official_Email" placeholder="Enter Official Email" >
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                <label for="Profile_Photo">Profile Photo</label>
                <input type="file" name="Profile_Photo" class="form-control"  required>
            </div>

            <hr style="width: 100%">
            <h3>Documents 1</h3>
            <hr style="width: 100%">

            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="images">image</label>
                <input type="file" name="images[]" class="form-control" multiple required>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="type">type</label>
                <input type="text" name="type[]" class="form-control" required>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="Document_number">Document number</label>
                <input type="number" name="Document_number[]" class="form-control" required>
            </div>

            <hr style="width: 100%">
            <h3>Documents 2</h3>
            <hr style="width: 100%">

            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="images">image</label>
                <input type="file" name="images[]" class="form-control" multiple required>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="type">type</label>
                <input type="text" name="type[]" class="form-control" required>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="Document_number">Document number</label>
                <input type="number" name="Document_number[]" class="form-control" required>
            </div>



            <hr style="width: 100%">
            <h3>Documents 3</h3>
            <hr style="width: 100%">

            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="images">image</label>
                <input type="file" name="images[]" class="form-control" multiple required>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="type">type</label>
                <input type="text" name="type[]" class="form-control" required>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="Document_number">Document number</label>
                <input type="number" name="Document_number[]" class="form-control" required>
            </div>


            <hr style="width: 100%">
            <h3>Documents 4</h3>
            <hr style="width: 100%">

            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="images">image</label>
                <input type="file" name="images[]" class="form-control" multiple required>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="type">type</label>
                <input type="text" name="type[]" class="form-control" required>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="Document_number">Document number</label>
                <input type="number" name="Document_number[]" class="form-control" required>
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">send</button>

        </div>
    </div>
    </section>
    <!-- /.content -->

</form>
```

This is the control code

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    // dd($request->all());

    if ($request->hasFile('Profile_Photo')) {
        $file_extension = $request->File('Profile_Photo')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $file_name = time() . '.' . $file_extension;
        $path = 'images/Profile_Photo';
        $request->File('Profile_Photo')->move($path, $file_name);
    } else {
        $file_name = "default.png";
    }

    $data['Profile_Photo'] = $file_name;
    $data['First_Name'] = $request->First_Name;
    $data['Last_Name'] = $request->Last_Name;
    $data['Birth_Date'] = $request->Birth_Date;
    $data['Official_Email'] = $request->Official_Email;

    $Employee = Employee::create($data);


    foreach ($request->type as $Doc) {

        $data_Document['employees_id'] = $Employee->id;

        // The error here is: Attempt to read property "type" on string
        $data_Document['Identity_type'] = $Doc->type;
        $data_Document['Document_number'] = $Doc->Document_number;

        $Document = $Employee->Document()->create($data_Document);

        // The error here is: Call to a member function file() on string
        foreach ($Doc->file('images') as $img) {
            $image_name = time() . rand(1, 999) . '.' . $img->extension();
            $path = 'images/Documentation';
            $img->move($path, $image_name);

            $Employee->Document()->Images()->create([
                'employees_id' => $Document->id,
                'image' => $image_name,
            ]);
        }
    }

    return redirect()->route('employees.index')->with(['success' => 'Content added successfully']);
}
```

This error appears to me
// The error here is: Attempt to read property "type" on string
// The error here is: Call to a member function file() on string

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so clear as to what it is exactly you are trying to do. The attribute **text** in the input field  `<input type="text" name="type[]" class="form-control" required>` is for whatever reason passed as an array. Are you trying to add multiple types? Iterate through the images themeselves

Comment: By type I mean the document type (Identity type).

Comment: I have fields of type(Identity type) repeated by name so I put it as an array.

Comment: I need to enter one or more types of documents later and each of them contains details such as number, type and multiple image